# Strangly slow email downloading on Windows 7 - 64

Tags: windows-7, email

I have been using an email package called pocomail for many years now and have installed it on a wide variety of machines. It has worked perfectly well and briskly on all of them except one... An Acer laptop with Windows-7/64bit.

The laptop itself is perfectly speedy for all tasks I throw at it other than pocomail email downloading. The slowdown is not subtle - its probably 10X slower than on any other machine. It's as if some human was manually reading each mail as is comes in!

If I leave the laptop for a while and the mail server has a couple of hundred (small, mostly attachment free) emails to download, it can take half an hour or more to download, whereas I can download the same lot on another PC on the same internet connection in a minute or two.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it's due to a plug in of your Poco software, or your anti virus (maybe the anti virus is a plug in). So, assuming your email account type is the same type as the other accounts you have (what I mean is, some accounts offer different packages, some are on POP3, others on exchange, there could be different loads on different servers, even different AV rules or programs etc) then I would install Outlook or a similar mail client and see if there is slow down with the other mail client. This may help you in where to focus (if the problem is a network issue or the Poco software on that machine etc).

It could even be a configuration in your Poco software although I don't know what.

Some times, and I'm sorry to say something so unscientific, but the classic "turn it off and on again" (or reinstall in your case) does cure a lot of these unknown issues!